# Under what conditions is the quotient of two definite integrals (over the same range and parameter) the integral of the quotient?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In the process of computing the posterior of a probability distribution, I realized I lack an understanding of when, given two continuous functions $ f(x) $ and $ g(x) $, it's the case that
$$
\frac{\int_{a}^b f(x) dx}{\int_a^b g(x) dx} = \int_a^b (f(x) / g(x)) dx.
$$

I can come up with simple cases where this property doesn't hold. For example, if $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x/2$, $ I = \int_a^b f(x) $, and $ J = \int_a^b g(x) $ then
$$
\frac{I}{J} = \frac{(b^2 - a^2)/2}{(b^2 - a^2)/4} = 2,
$$
whereas
$$
\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} dx = \int_a^b 2 dx = 2(b - a).
$$
Thus, the equality fails whenever $ b - a \neq 1 $.

Comment: Coming back to this after a few months, I'm pessimistic about getting a satisfying answer. It seems to me that the answer is very likely "almost always" since, geometrically, this property fails whenever the quotient of the area under the two functions for some range doesn't equal the area under the quotient of the two functions over the same range.

Comment: "Almost never", rather?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Good catch thanks!